# While a self-contained .NetCore app is running, what's the best way to start another .NetCore app sharing the same runtime?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a self-contained .net core app on Mac, and it contains another .net core app as a plugin.
The structure is somewhat like this:

```
MyApp.app
  |---Content
         |----MacOS
                |---self-contained runtime *dlls and assemblies
         |----Resources
                |---MyPlugin.app
```

Once MyApp is running, a user may start MyPlugin. I am hoping to share the runtimes under MacOS. What's the best way to do this?

Here is what I have tried based on what I read and tested, they could be all wrong...:

1. Since MyPlugin is using apphost, one way seems working is to set dotnet_root to *MyApp/Content/MacOS*. Then it will look for something like *$DOTNET_ROOT/shared/$name/$version*, but since MyApp is self-contained, it doesn't have this structure, which means I would need to make this structure myself.
2. I think nethost is made for non .netcore apps to start .netcore runtime, even I use this, it will face the same problem as the first way, I think.
3. Since Docker will isolate my app's environment, if I built my app using the .net core docker image, maybe both MyApp and MyPlguin would find the right .NetCore libraries. But I cannot assume users could run Docker.

Is there an easier or official way to do this? Since MyApp is already running when I start MyPlugin, is it possible to just reuse the already started runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked a similar question on github [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3453), and a .net team member confirmed it's not currently possible, and a workaround is using the 1st way described in the question.

Credit goes to Vitek Karas:

> What you could do instead is build the apps as framework dependent.
> Then when installing:
>
> - Get the "zip" download for the specific runtime version/target
> - Unzip it to some location - can be in "runtime" subfolder to your main folder
> - Install the apps as shown above (but really anywhere, it doesn't matter)
> - Run the apps via a "script" - all you need to do is set DOTNET_ROOT=path env. variable > to point to the runtime folder and then run the app from that environment. On Windows you may also want to set DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP=0 to make sure the apps will not use the globally installed .NET Core (if there's any).